# Method Not Allowed - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am getting error while updating. When i add data it is added successfully. This error is only comming for `UpdateAPIView`

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}
```

urls.py

```
path('groups/update/<int:pk>', views.GroupsUpdateAPIView.as_view(), name='api_groups_update'),
```

Views.py

```
class GroupsUpdateAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Groups.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupsAddSerialzer
    permission_classes = [UserIsAuthenticated]

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(
            group_updated_by = self.request.auth.application.user,
        )
```

Serializer.py

```
class GroupsAddSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Groups
        fields = ['group_name', 'group_description', 'group_status']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`UpdateAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updateapiview) view uses the HTTP methods `PUT` and `PATCH`. The method `POST` is used to create a new instance with [`CreateAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) view.